# Redirection not working after admin login in Django

Tags: python, django

If a staff user is not logged in and an admin URL is entered in the browser such as:

```
https://api.myproj.net/admin/somepage/
```

... then the redirect URL that appears in the browser is (incorrect):

```
https://api.myproj.net/admin/login/?next=/admin/%3Fnext%3D/admin/somepage/
```

So after logging in the final URL is:

```
https://api.myproj.net/admin/?next=/admin/somepage/
```

... instead of (what is should be):

```
https://api.myproj.net/admin/somepage/
```

In settings.py I have set up the URLs to suit staff logins:

```
LOGIN_URL = '/admin/'
LOGOUT_URL = '/admin/logout/'
```

In urls.py the admin URLs are specified as follows:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/somepage/?$', login_required(somepage), name='somepage'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    ...
]
```

I am using Django 1.8.5.

Comment: There is already a built-in login control system for admin. And you are making another one for `admin/somepage` manually. Don't know your code's details, but it may be related.

Comment: @alix If I take out the url pattern for somepage then I get a 404 error when going to https://api.myproj.net/admin/somepage/

Comment: @alix Yes, you're right about using the admin system.  I should be defining these URLs in admin.py instead.